# SQL select from multiple tables sql-ex 6

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to solve the task number 6 from [sql-ex.com](http://www.sql-ex.com), but I have stuck.

The problem is next:

For each maker producing laptops with a hard drive capacity of 10 Gb or higher, find the speed of such laptops. Result set: maker, speed.
The database scheme consists of four tables:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

Here it is my current code:

```
select Product.maker, speed from Laptop left join Product
on Laptop.model=Product.model
where hd>=10
```

It isn't correct.

Comment: it isnt correct ... can you elaborate it

Comment: No need for LEFT JOIN here, regular inner join will do.

Comment: May be add `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying. Here is the message I get: "Incorrect. Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
* Wrong number of records (more by 2)." Actually, I do get the result they are looking for, but with this message, which says it isn't correct.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, you are right. Thank you! :) It is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

It should contain DISTINCT:

```
select DISTINCT Product.maker, speed from Laptop left join Product
on Laptop.model=Product.model
where hd>=10
```